# Issue saving file with AHK

Tags: excel, autohotkey

Trying to write a loop that takes data from a read-only Excel file, and pastes it into a separate Excel file. Everything in this code works great, other than it is not saving the file. Here is all my code:

```
#q::
savefile := "path"

loop
{
  xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application") ;Create handle
  xl.Visible := true
  xl.Range("A:I").Copy ;copy cell to clipboard
  Sleep, 500
  xl_Workbook := xl.Workbooks.Open("path") ;Open output workbook
  Sleep, 500
  xl.Range("A:I").Select ;Ensure proper area of worksheet is being used
  Sleep, 500
  xl.ActiveSheet.Paste ;Paste into output
  Sleep, 3000
  xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(savefile)
  Sleep, 3500
  xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close() ;Close workbook
  Sleep, 60000
} return
```

I have tried using just:

```
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
```

but still, no luck.

Comment: Googled [an article](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm) that says the format should be specified explicitly: `xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(savefile, 51)`

Answer (score 0):

Re-started computer and the code worked... very odd, but it works!